# Self Signed Certificate Swift Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to query an endpoint that includes HTTPS and Self Signed Certificate.  How would I implement the code below to include a certificate using Combine in Swift.

```
struct API {
    
    func getJSON() -> AnyPublisher<ResultList, Error> {
        let url = URL(string:urlString)!
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map({$0.data})
            .decode(type: ResultList.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

For example without using Combine I normally do the following:

```
class SessionDelegate: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {
    
    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        
        if challenge.protectionSpace.host == myCert {
            completion(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
        } else {
            completion(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with `URLSession.shared`, because the session's delegate has to accept the self-signed certificate.

Your question shows that you already know how to use a delegate for this. So change `getJSON` to accept an appropriately-delegated session as an argument:

```
    func getJSON(with session: URLSession) -> AnyPublisher<ResultList, Error> {
        let url = URL(string:urlString)!
        return session.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map({$0.data})
            .decode(type: ResultList.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```